# How do you store a certain part of a string into a variable?

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-language, game-maker-studio-2

How do you store a certain part of a string into a variable?

For example:

```
x = myString // - But store the 9th character into a variable
```

Comment: Use the well documented String functions to get the 9th char. https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/strings/string_char_at.html

Answer (score 0):

This gets a single character from a string:

```
var x = string_char_at("This is my string", 4); //X == "s"
```

And you can use the [string_copy](https://docs2.yoyogames.com/source/_build/3_scripting/4_gml_reference/strings/string_copy.html) function to copy parts of a string;

```
var x = string_copy("This is my string", 8, 2); //X == "my"
```

Comment: The question is very short and to the point - the answer is very short and to the point. This person is looking for a function. The answer is the function. Please, read the question before you vote to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
x = string_char_at(myString , 9);
```